# Customize viewport navigation

Tags: 3d-view, customization

I have a problem with customize hotkeys. For example I want to change Zoom in viewport hotkey from "Ctrl + MMB" to "1 + LMB" how can I do that? I found this command in input preferences, and I can change to any letters hotkeys + Mouse Button, but if I change to numbers + Mouse Button - it's not working.

I'm customized this in Maya and used to it some years ago and it's very convenient for me, so I would like to do the same in Blender.

Comment: What didn't work and what did you try? Note that if assigning 1 (not from Numpad) to another action you need to disable it from layers toggle (3D View (global) > Layers in User Prefs > Input). Also for the property for zooming you change (Zoom View) make sure to change event to Click. Once it's done 1 will invoke zooming and moving mouse will allow change it. Press 1 again to exit.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not quite :( I want to avoid double clicking, because it's slow, I would like to do Press\Release commands like a Maya - for example when I press and hold "1" key I can drag left mouse button and zoomed, but if I release, I will return to previous state.

Comment: I solved the problem, I had a tick Emulate Numpad in left side of Input Preferences.